# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: java, exception, pointers, null

I'm trying to run a program that will, if all goes well, be able to take a year and return the title of an album released in that year. I've given it 6 albums already and I'm now trying to actually print a title. I've fixed a few pretty frustrating errors, but this is one I've not seen before. The error appears at line 21, but I'm not sure what it means. Can anyone help?

```
package songselector;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public class Album
    {
int year; String title;
public Album () {
this.year = 0; this.title = null;
        }
public Album (int year, String title) {
this.year = year; this.title = title;
     }
    }

   class CAKE {
Album[] albums;
public CAKE () {
albums = new Album[6];
albums[0].year = 1994; albums[0].title = "Motorcade Of Generosity";
albums[1].year = 1996; albums[1].title = "Fashion Nugget";
albums[2].year = 1998; albums[2].title = "Prolonging The Magic";
albums[3].year = 2001; albums[3].title = "Comfort Eagle";
albums[4].year = 2004; albums[4].title = "Pressure Chief";
albums[5].year = 2011; albums[5].title = "Showroom of Compassion";
     }

public void printAlbum (int y) {
System.out.println (albums[y].title);
    }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().new CAKE().printAlbum (0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you are trying to access / call a method on an object which is null. In your case, you initialized the array of Albums, but didn't initialize each of the albums in the array.

You need to initialize each album in the array:

```
albums = new Album[6];
albums[0] = new Album();
albums[0].year = 1994; 
albums[0].title = "Motorcade Of Generosity";
...
```

Or even simpler (as @entonio pointed out):

```
albums = new Album[6];
albums[0] = new Album(1994, "Motorcade Of Generosity");
albums[1] = new Album(1996, "Fashion Nugget");
...
```

Since you have a proper constructor.

One more thing: don't call more than one method in each line, it will help you debugging.

Comment: It's `albums[0]`, and using his ctor it can be `albums[0] = new Album(1994, "Motorcade Of Generosity");`

Comment: Ah, alright. Thank you, that makes sense. It's running fine now.

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate an array of objects, it's filled with null values. You need to create objects to fill them. Your `albums[0]` wasn't created, so trying to access its `year` field (even for writing) results in a NPE.

Comment: Thanks, I'd have proposed an edit but I still don't know very well how SO works. I only pointed out the missing -s because I did think the OP might get confused. I have great respect for all of you here who write proper thorough replies with actual code, I'm not very good with formatting and so sometimes I just try to explain what I think the OP needs to know in order to solve the problem.